# Using insert into using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I need to insert the following into my table...My users table has five columns id, username, password, name, entry. (im not submitting anything into entry just yet i will use php to do that later on) but for some reason i keep getting this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'const89' in 'field list' Why is it reading the value as a column?

```
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(1,const89,cdm89,constantin);
```

I have also tried `INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,name) VALUES(1,const89,cdm89,constantin);`
which gives me the same exact error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your strings in quotes:

```
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(1,'const89','cdm89','constantin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put quotes around your strings:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1,'const89','cdm89','constantin');
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your string values within quotes.

```
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(1,'const89','cdm89','constantin');
```

Comment: @slugonamission - I've edited the answer even before your comment :), you're right, thanks.